# How do I access promise result later on?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

```
var screencastId = 'abc'

var a = youtube.get(screencastId);
a.then(function(screencast) {
  // Yay. I have the screencast information here.
  console.log(screencast);
});

// How do I access the `screencast` variable down here?
connection.beginTransactionAsync().then(function() {
  return connection.queryAsync('INSERT IGNORE INTO Channels SET ?', screencast.channel);
}).then(function() {
  return connection.queryAsync('INSERT INTO Screencasts SET ?', screencast);
}).then(function() {
  var values = tags.map(function(tag) { return [tag]; });
  return connection.queryAsync('INSERT IGNORE INTO Tags VALUES ?', [values])
}).then(function() {
  var values = tags.map(function(tag) { return [screencast.screencastId, tag]; });
  return connection.queryAsync('INSERT INTO ScreencastTags VALUES ?', [values])
}).then(function() {
  return connection.commit();
}).error(function(e) {
  connection.rollback();
  winston.error(e);
});
```

This code can be broken down into two discrete steps:

1. Download information about a `screencast` hosted on YouTube using the `youtube` module.
2. Store information about that `screencast` in the database.

Both of the steps are asynchronous, naturally.

My question is, **how do I access the `screencast` argument in the second step?**

I found [*this comprehensive answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain), but as someone relatively inexperienced with JS, I cannot work out how to apply that answer here.

Comment: As the author of the comprehensive answer(s), I'd like to know: What are you missing? How could I improve the answers? Btw, I think that [nesting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/1048572) is the best solution for your case.

Comment: What approach from the ones listed in the canonical question did you choose? Can you show us how you tried to apply it to your code, please? I'd be happy to reopen this question and help you with your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two ways:

1. Create a global variable `screencast` (like you already have a `screencastId`) which is shared between all `.then` calls
2. If for some reason you cannot use a global variable there you also can return in every `.then` statement a `new Promise` where in `resolve` function you pass a parameter `screencast`

So this is the first way how I see it (but unfortunately cannot test):

```
var screencastId = 'abc', screencast

youtube.get(screencastId)
.then(function(sc) {
  screencast = sc;
})

// you need this to keep the chain
.then(function(){
  return connection.beginTransactionAsync()
})

.then(function() {
  return connection.queryAsync('INSERT IGNORE INTO Channels SET ?', screencast.channel);
}).then(function() {
  return connection.queryAsync('INSERT INTO Screencasts SET ?', screencast);
}).then(function() {
  var values = tags.map(function(tag) { return [tag]; });
  return connection.queryAsync('INSERT IGNORE INTO Tags VALUES ?', [values])
}).then(function() {
  var values = tags.map(function(tag) { return [screencast.screencastId, tag]; });
  return connection.queryAsync('INSERT INTO ScreencastTags VALUES ?', [values])
}).then(function() {
  return connection.commit();
}).error(function(e) {
  connection.rollback();
  winston.error(e);
});
```

**Returning the new Promise example**:

```
youtube.get(screencastId)
.then(function(sc) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    resolve(sc)
  })
})
.then(function(sc){
  console.log(sc)
})
```

Comment: I did not think about that! Could I please see an example of returning a new `Promise`?

Comment: added a small example of it. You always can make a function which generates a new promise with sc to avoid this big structure in every then statement

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can have a glovar variable globalScreencast and in your first step do something like that :

```
a.then(function(screencast) {
    // Yay. I have the screencast information here.
    console.log(screencast);
    globalScreencast = screencast;
});
```

so then in your second step you can have access to the variable